# Difference between OUTPUT WHEN and WHERE in Esper

Tags: java, esper

I have a very basic Esper question,what is the basic difference between OUTPUT WHEN and WHERE key word in Esper. Here is an example where i am using these Key Words.

```
select
  high
from 
  Bar
where
  getDirection() != Direction.FLAT;
```

and

```
select
  high
from 
  Bar
output when
  getDirection() != Direction.FLAT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"output when" batches up output until the condition turns true.

Always prefer filters over where-clauses: select high from Bar (direction != Direction.FLAT)

Answer (score 1):

`select high from Bar where getDirection() != Direction.FLAT;` --> This statement will returns all you value in which `getDirection()!= Direction.FLAT`. It is something like you are comparing the values of that table with external values.

`select high from Bar when getDirection() != Direction.FLAT;` --> This statement returns all the values from `Bar` when your `getDirection() != Direction.FLAT` It is like you are fetching the values when certain condition is true.